# How to use flow_from_directory in Keras for multi-class semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, keras

Let's say I have 100 training grayscale images and 100 RGB training masks, each of size 512x512. I was able to one-hot encode the masks using `to_categorical` in Keras with the below

```
numclasses=3
masks_one_hot=to_categorical(maskArr,numclasses)
```

where `maskArr` is a 100x512x512x1, and `masks_one_hot` is 100x512x512x3.

However, to use `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory` using `trainGenerator` from https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/data.py, I tried to save the one-hot encoded training images and then read them using `trainGenerator`. However, I noticed after using `imwrite` on them and then reading them with `imread`, they changed from one-hot encoded 512x512x3 to 512x512x3 RGB images. That is, instead of each channel having a value of 0 or 1, they now range from 0-255

As a result, if I do:

```
myGenerator = trainGeneratorOneHot(20,'data/membrane/train','image','label',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = "data/membrane/train/aug", flag_multi_class = True,
num_class = 3, target_size=(512,512,3))

num_batch=3
for i,batch in enumerate(myGenerator):
    if(i >= num_batch):
        break
```

where `trainGeneratorOneHot` is below:

```
def trainGeneratorOneHot(batch_size,...class_mode=None, image_class_mode=None):

    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,classes = [image_folder], class_mode = image_class_mode, color_mode = image_color_mode,target_size = target_size, ...)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, classes = [mask_folder], class_mode = class_mode, target_size = target_size,...)
    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

    for (img,mask) in train_generator:
        img,mask = adjustDataOneHot(img,mask)
        yield (img,mask)

def adjustDataOneHot(img,mask):
    return (img,mask)
```

Then I get `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,1) into shape (512,512,3,1)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Was dealing with the same issue a few days ago. I found it essential to make my own data generator class to deal with taking in data from a dataframe, augmenting it, and then one-hot-encoding it before passing it to my model. I was never able to get the Keras `ImageDataGenerator` to work for semantic segmentation problems with multiple classes.

Below is a data generator class in case it might help you out:

```py
def one_hot_encoder(mask, num_classes = 8):

    hot_mask = np.zeros(shape = mask.shape, dtype = 'uint8')

    for _ in range(8):
        temp = np.zeros(shape = mask.shape[0:2], dtype = 'uint8')
        temp[mask[:, :, _] != 0] = 1
        hot_mask[:, :, _] = temp

    return hot_mask

# Image data generator class
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, dataframe, batch_size, n_classes = 8, augment = False):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.augment = augment


    # Steps per epoch    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe) // self.batch_size

    # Shuffles and resets the index at the end of training epoch
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.dataframe = self.dataframe.reset_index(drop = True)


    # Generates data, feeds to training
    def __getitem__(self, index):

        processed_images = []
        processed_masks = []

        for _ in range(self.batch_size):

            the_image = io.imread(self.dataframe['Images'][index])
            the_mask = io.imread(self.dataframe['Masks'][index]).astype('uint8');
            one_hot_mask = one_hot_encoder(the_mask, 8)


            if(self.augment):
                # Resizing followed by some augmentations
                processed_image = augs_for_images(image = the_image) / 255.0
                processed_mask = augs_for_masks(image = one_hot_mask)


            else:
                # Still resizing but no augmentations   
                processed_image = resize(image = the_image) / 255.0
                processed_mask = resize(image = one_hot_mask)

            processed_images.append(processed_image)
            processed_masks.append(processed_mask)


        batch_x = np.array( processed_images )
        batch_y = np.array( processed_masks )

        return (batch_x, batch_y)
```

Also, here's a link to a repo with some semantic segmentation models that might be of interest to you. The [notebook](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models/blob/master/examples/multiclass%20segmentation%20(camvid).ipynb) itself shows how the author dealt with multi-class semantic segmentation.